# How xor this values to gether?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have two values 1D and 06 how can xor this values in javascript i have xor this two values as follows
console.log('1D' ^ '06') i got a mistake answer in console can any one help me.

Comment: Probably you should convert the strings into numbers. Probably HEX. However, your question is very unclear, please add more details, and elaborate on your problem. Please read [ask] and https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Comment: Did you mean to use `0x1D ^ 0x6`? The `'1D'` string doesn't convert to a number correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can prefix it with '0x' to indicate a hex value, and it will work.

```
console.log('0x1D' ^ '0x06')
27
```